# Можно ли взаимодействовать с админкой WordPress с помощью кода?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, node.js

Допустим, мне нужно натянуть верстку на `WordPress`, но руками выбирать типы полей, писать однотипные инструкции к ним и перетаскивать эти поля мышкой, соблюдая структуру очень долго и нудно. Поэтому возникла такая идея: верстать с помощью data-атрибутов. Далее пробегаться по html файлу и в зависимости от этих атрибутов програмно добавлять поля, назначая им тип, описания, инструкцию и формировать таким образом нужную структуру страницы. Только мне нужно как-то взаимодействовать с админкой. Это нужно искать кнопки и поля по `id` на странице wp-admin и эмулировать на них клик?

Попробую переформулировать:

1. У меня есть плагин Advanced custom fields

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Я могу добавить заголовок для группы полей, поля, их описание и категорию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Я не хочу заполнять это все руками. Поэтому у меня есть такая верстка:

```
<p class = "fullscreen__text" data-field-type = "text" data-is-required = "true" data-instructions = "add your text on fullscreen block" > <?php get_field('fullsreen_text'); ?> </p>
```

Можно ли программно вытащить Все значения data-атрибутов и создать с их помощью новое поле? В какой файл надо вносить изменения для этого?

Comment: Непонятно про что ты вообще - вертска не делается в админке. Через админку сайт наполняется контентом и производятся его настройка-администрирование.

Comment: @SeVlad Я про наполнение сайта. Верстка уже готова. Там есть заголовки, текста и картинки, которые надо менять через админку. Для этого нужно создать поля (которые связываются с версткой через get_field() в wordpress) Я не хочу руками создавать все эти поля, а сформировать структуру php-документа программно.

Comment: @SeVlad Отредактировал вопрос, простите, надо было сразу добавлять скриншоты)

Comment: Теперь я увидел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создавать поля ACF программно, php-кодом. Для этого в плагине ACF существует свой [API](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/).

В вашем php-коде можно просканировать html-файл на наличие data-атрибутов и создать нужные поля.

Comment: Кажется, это то, что мне было нужно, буду разбираться, огромное спасибо!